# Is there any issue with the mouse drag scroll event in the tkinter library?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent, tkinter-canvas

I am using the tkinter library.

I want to make the screen scroll work by clicking and moving in the Y-axis direction within the canvas,

but with the current code, the canvas does not move at all.

Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

```
def create_gallery_frame(self):
        self.gallery_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#FAFAD2")
        self.gallery_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.gallery_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=30)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.gallery_frame, borderwidth=0, background="#FFFFFF", highlightthickness=0)
        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#FFFFFF")

        self.scrollable_frame_id = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        self.scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_scroll)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.do_scroll)

        self.canvas.config(width=900, height=500)

        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.load_and_display_images()

def start_scroll(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def do_scroll(self, event):
        # scrolling to only the y axis
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.y, gain=2)

def load_and_display_images(self):
        image_folder = "./picture/"
        image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

        row, column = 0, 1
        for image_file in image_files:
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(image_folder, image_file))
            img_resized = img.resize((200, 200), Image.LANCZOS)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)

            img_label = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame, image=photo)
            img_label.image = photo
            img_label.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=35, pady=15)

            column += 1
            if column > 3:  
                column = 1  
                row += 1
```

Comment: First you need to drag on the canvas, not on the internal frame or those images.  Second the function `.scan_dragto()` requires at least two positional arguments `x` and `y`, but you provide only one.